# JavaScript not running after SignalR connection

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using `SignalR` for the first time, alongside `mdb charts`. I am using an alert to prove that `SignalR` is working and it successfully gets my data.

I tried adding some example chart code and it just doesn't display the graph. The code works fine when called using a `click` function.

I was thinking it could be a timing issue, as the current update is from OnGetAsync, and it might be received before the document loads?

I basically want to send live graph data to the page and have it update in real time.

**Razor Page:**

```
<div class="col">
   <canvas id="myGraph" style="max-width: 500px" class="mr-2"</canvas>
</div>
```

**js**:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/graphs").build();

(function ($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    $(document).ready(function () {

   var ctxL2 = document.getElementById("myGraph").getContext('2d');
    var openTick = new Chart(ctxL2, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["Monday", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "New User Requests",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(105, 0, 132, .7)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(200, 99, 132, .9)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });

    connection.on("sendGraphData", function (graphdata) {
        alert(graphdata);
        openTick.data = {
            labels: ["Monday", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "New User Requests",
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(23,208,206,0.69)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(200, 99, 132, .9)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        };
        openTick.update();
    });


    $("#test-two").click(function () {
        openTick.data = {
            labels: ["Monday", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "New User Requests",
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(23,208,206,0.69)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(200, 99, 132, .9)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        };
        openTick.update();
    });

        connection.start().catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });

     });
})(window.jQuery);  //Update from post below.
```

**cshtml.cs:**

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
     {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/graphs",options => {
                options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .AddJsonProtocol(options => {
                options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new DefaultContractResolver();
            })
            .Build();

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("sendGraphData", mydata);

        await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any errors with your signalR connection? Just because it's working doesn't mean it's not throwing any errors. Open up Developer Tools in Chrome, and see if any are being reported.

Comment: I don't have errors, just Information: Normalizing '/graphs' to 'https://localhost:5001/graphs' and Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:5001/graphs?id=HUlTQNpLEK0V3ApBEw1_iQ. Thanks.

Comment: Above information has no influence.Do you mean `alert(graphdata);` works when you invoke in the razor pages handler using hubconnection but other js logic has error?Your openTick.data  and how the graph is shown is not clear.

Comment: I have added more code to try and make it clearer. I was originally trying to draw the whole graph in the SignalR call, but I changed it to update only and rendered the original graph on page load. The alert triggers which suggests the SignalR works. I also put the update code in a click function to test it, and the code works fine there - the graph updates as expected. I just cant update it which SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had to make the request from the javascript so that it only received the data when the page was ready.

```
    connection.start().then(function (value) { 
        connection.invoke("testData");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped the code underneath SignalR in a function, but you have not passed a parameter for `$`. Try this (I've added a bit of code at the bottom):

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/graphs").build();



(function ($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    $(document).ready(function () {

 connection.on("sendGraphData", function (graphdata) {
            alert(graphdata);

            var ctxL2 = document.getElementById("myGraph").getContext('2d');
            var myNewGraph = new Chart(ctxL2, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Monday", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "New User Requests",
                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(105, 0, 132, .7)',
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(200, 99, 132, .9)',
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 2
                    }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true
                }
            });

        });

        connection.start().catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });

     });
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I messed up and didn't copy it with my sample code :(. Will update post.